# How to force HDFS to use LDAP user's UID

Tags: authentication, hadoop, permissions, ldap, hdfs

I have a cloudera cluster with HDFS and Hue services and I'm trying to unify the authentication using LDAP.

I have my LDAP server running thanks to 389-ds (not sure if is the best way) and I can log into Hue with users from the LDAP server. When I login for first time, Hue creates the home directory in the HDFS.

But is not using the UID I set when I added the user to the LDAP server.
It wouldn't be a problem if I just access the HDFS via Hue but I also have a machine with the HDFS mounted via NFS.

I'm also having problems to add LDAP authentication in the machine with the NFS mount. I can do `su username` (username being a user in the LDAP server) and the system adds a home directory, but I cannot authenticate via SSH using LDAP users. I need this to avoid adding local users too.

My main question is: How to force HDFS or Hue to use the same UID I set when I create LDAP users.

**More details:**

I have configured LDAP in cloudera for both Hue and Hadoop (not sure if the latter is using it properly)
I know I could, maybe, change the UID a posteriori to the one set by Hue at the first login, but is more a workaround than a clean solution.

**Pictures:**

In this example, potato user has an uid 10104, but if I do `ls -la /users/potato` in the NFS mount, it says that the folder belongs to a user with uid 3312528423.

[image: Example of user in the 389-DS]
[image: POSIX details of the LDAP user]